# Fastest way to detect non-equal strings (without storing the string)?

Tags: c#, string, performance, equality

I am writing a templating engine and I am searching for a good way to detect if a template has changed.

For this I have the following requirements (in order of importance):

- non-equal strings are required to be detected different
- as fast as possible
- as less memory as possible (=> do not store the whole string for comparison)
- high propability to detect equal strings as equal

It is not a big problem, if sometimes equal strings are not detected as equal as this would just trigger a "re-rendering" which would not be needed, but because of the "heavy work" of this, this should happen as less as possible.

I first thought of using `String.GetHashCode()`, but the probalility of getting the same hash-code for two non-equal strings is pretty high.

Are there any good combinations like checking hash-code and `Length` to get the probability of to non-equal strings wrongly detected as equal to an unrealisticly happening low number?

Or is using some hashing algorithm, like MD5 or SHA, a good alternative (after hash-code is equal)?

My rendering looks something like the following:

```
public string RenderTemplate(string name, string template)
{
    var cachedTemplate = Cache.Get(name);
    if(cachedTemplate == null || !cachedTemplate.Equals(template)) // <= Equals
    {
        cachedTemplate = new Template(name, template);
        cachedTemplate.Render();
        Cache.Set(name, cachedTemplate);
    }

    return cachedTemplate.Result;
}
```

The `Equals` is the point I am asking about.

I am also open for other suggestions how this could be solved.

**UPDATE:**
To add some numbers to get more context:
I expect to have >1000 individual templates and each template will have up to at least a few thousand characters.
This is why I would like to avoid storing the whole template-string "in memory" only for the comparison.
Most of the templates are stored in the DB.

**UPDATE 2:**
What do you think about extending my `RenderTemplate` method with a `timestamp` as suggested by Nikola:

```
public string RenderTemplate(string name, string template, DateTime timestamp)
```

Then I could compare `name`, `GetHashCode` and `timestamp` which does not need much memory, should be pretty fast and the probability of a "wrongly detected equality" is practically 0. The `timestamp` I can read from the DB (have it already there) or the "last changed date" from the file-system for a file-based template.

Comment: Could you distinguish between _strings_ and _lines_ and indicate where things are stored? On disk?

Comment: The probability of two non-equal strings having the same hash code is approximately 1/(2^32).  That's a pretty small number.  That is, unless your strings happen to fulfill some sort of pattern such that the hashing algorithm fails to evenly distribute the hases.  That, or you really have hundreds of thousands of strings...

Comment: Did you actually code the program just using traditional string methods and find that it was too slow?  Honestly, given what you're describing, I'd actually be rather surprised if fairly standard string operations would be insufficient for your purposes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I don't understand what you mean by `distinguish between strings and lines` but for the storage: Thats different. Some/most templates are stored in the DB an some are files on the disk.

Comment: If you are comparing to a stored template, when you store the template, store a hash of the entire template. Compare the hash of the changed template to the stored as a starting point. Progressively refine your comparisons, if necessary, to find the changed strings. And do not use MD5 or SHA as a hashing algorithm as they are both BROKEN.

Comment: @NickZimmerman MD5 and SHA are likely insufficient for a security related hash, but this isn't a security related hash, but rather a performance based one.

Comment: @Servy - You wouldn't want to rely on chances for a problem where 100% is easily achievable. And they are a little bigger than the simple `1/(2^32).

Comment: If you're about to persist a string, don't use .Net's `GetHashCode()`. As the documentation states, these hashes can differ per assembly and should not be persisted.

Comment: @Servy: According to some articles I wrote the probability is much less then 1/(2^32) (birthday problem) and is >1% starting at a few thousand strings. Using "traditional string methods" not the speed is the problem, but the requirement to store the "old string" for comparison for all methods I could think of.

Comment: @chrfin - then don't call templates strings, or whatever. It still reads cluttered and ambiguous. For a serious answer we'd also have to know how many, how big. Roughly.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, which is why I said "approximately".  It should be at least in that ballpark.  Assuming you actually do a check of the content to cover collisions, it's likely to be sufficient.  As for why you'd want to do that, if that *is* sufficient it means just using a `HashSet<string>` and not writing your own data structure, your own hashing algorithm, maintaining all of that code, ensuring there are no mistakes, etc.

Comment: @Servy - collisions are the expected case here.

Comment: @chrfin I think you're overestimating the cost of doing an actual comparison of the strings, in the event of collisions.  Yes, if you have a few hundred thousand strings you have a couple percent change of a collision.  That's really *not* likely to be problematic.  If you were comparing all of the bits of each of several hundred thousand large strings each time you wanted to modify the set, then sure, that'd be a problem.  Doing just one a few percent of the time, not a problem.

Comment: @Servy: But I still would need to store the "old string" which is what I want to avoid, as they can be rather large and many of them. I will add some numbers to the question...

Comment: @HenkHolterman Unless he has millions of strings, his odds of collisions is still likely in the low single digits.  Given that the cost of a single collision is not all that high, I don't see a major problem here.  The odds of a programmer making a mistake in writing a `HashSet` based on a 512 bit hash seems more likely to be a problem.

Comment: I don't think .Equals() is even a bottleneck here. Also calling GetHashCode() for comparison will be slower since it's computed each time you call it, unless you store the hash code and update it when the template is changed ( but you'd already be solving the problem here wouldn't you )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have much choice. If you don't compare strings by comparing their content, use a hash algorithm to determine if strings are equal. Personally, I would probably use a hash algorithm. If you are a bit paranoid and afraid of a collision, choose algorithm with widest space (e.g. SHA512).

Why do you need to compare strings to determine that a template has changed? Why not use a different approach?

- If file is stored on disk, why not use a file watcher?
- If stored in database, why not use a timestamp to detect when it was saved?
- If application is restarted, anyway reload templates

Also, it's worrying that a template for UI changes so often that you must make checks like this. I think you have more problems with design beside comparing strings.

Comment: Using a hash algorithm won't tell you if strings are equal. It will only tell you if they are *not* equal. Two different strings can have the same hash.

Comment: That is clear. That's why I wouldn't use it for making important decisions, but I would trust it with comparing template for user interface which is even in case of hash collision going to eventually be reloaded and will make no damage. Also, for this particular purpose, I'll stress again that there is no reason to compare template content to see if it changed if you can use row version or file watcher.